# How to use single .node binary module file in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, node.js-addon

I just want to use my custom build binary module which is only one single file *index.node*. It's located in *src/modules/my_module* directory. When I try to use it in my lambda function

```
const myModule = require('src/modules/my_module')
```

it throws error that

> Failure: Cannot find module

I even tried like this

```
const myModule = require('src/modules/my_module/index.node')
```

then it throws

> Module parse failed

but if I run the same code in node.js (without deploying in aws lambda) it works. How to load node.js binary module files in AWS Lambda functions properly?

**@AironBrynchke**

Just repeat following steps:

```
mkdir myprj 
cd myprj 
serverless create --template aws-nodejs-typescript && npm install 
cp /folder/with/your/index.node ./index.node 
nano handler.ts
```

then replace to this content

```
import { APIGatewayEvent, Callback, Context, Handler } from 'aws-lambda';

export const hello: Handler = (event: APIGatewayEvent, context: Context, cb: Callback) => {
  const myModule = require('./index.node');
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: 'Go Serverless Webpack (Typescript) v1.0! Your function executed successfully!',
      input: event,
    }),
  };

  cb(null, response);
}
```

then final step

```
serverless deploy -v
```

you will see

> ERROR in ./index.node 1:0 Module parse failed: Unexpected character
>   '' (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   (Source code omitted for this binary file)  @ ./handler.ts 2:21-44  @
>   multi ./source-map-install.js ./handler.ts

I also tried to install node loader for webpack

```
npm install node-loader --save-dev
```

and then add in webpack.config.js

```
module: {
    rules: [
      // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
      { use: 'node-loader'}
    ],
  },
```

after all I got this error

> ERROR in .../myprj/handler.ts(1,21)
>         TS2339: Property 'dlopen' does not exist on type 'Process'.

Comment: Hi! Are you sure that you included that folder to your current build? Can you share a screenshot of the package structure? And also check this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-directory

Comment: @AironBrynchke I just updated my question. Please follow exact steps what I described to replicate such issue

Comment: You have to transpile your TS files into JS files. Check this out: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript

Comment: @AironBrynchke webpack already transpile everything to js automatically

Comment: I mean why you have that file handler.ts ?

Comment: @AironBrynchke this file generated by serverless template webpack transpile this file to javascript before deployment so final output is js

Comment: Yes, that file is an entry point for your lambda function. But still, why it's handler.ts in your error log? Can I have a screenshot of your deployment package structure?